# How to type `->| len |<-` to indicate the length of segment?

Tags: symbols

How could I display like following:

[image]

I looked up some handbooks but couldn't find the command to display symbols [image] and [image]. Or are they draw by tikz ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with predefined symbols but it's not difficult to build them; no `tikz` needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\rightarrowvert}{\mbox{\mathsurround\z@$\rightarrow$\llap{\rule{.5pt}{2ex}}}}
\newcommand*{\vertleftarrow}{\mbox{\mathsurround\z@\rlap{\rule{.5pt}{2ex}}$\leftarrow$}}
\newcommand*{\showlength}[1]{%
   \rightarrowvert
   \kern#1\relax
   \ifdim#1>\z@ \expandafter\@gobbletwo\fi\raisebox{1ex}%
   \vertleftarrow
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showlength{0.1667em}
\quad
\showlength{0.5em}
\quad
\showlength{-0.1667em}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using picture mode one could have rounded caps for the vertical line too...

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @ BlueHeart0621 if the answer of campa helped you, you may consider to accept the answer. :)